# "This Project Out of Date: ..."

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2017

My MFC/C++ project Builds.  When I Debug it, only a couple source files show "The breakpoint will not currently be hit - no symbols have been loaded for this document".  In Visual Studio, when I select "Local Windows Debugger", I get "This Project Out of Date: ...".  I've followed other posts to rectify and I've set Tools/Options/Projects & Solutions/Build and Run = Detailed.  I've cleaned.  I've Rebuilt.  I've deleted *.tlog files.  Noting allowed me to debug the few source files.  Then I noticed this:

1>Project not up to date because build input 'E:\Users\Valued Customer\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MA2v52\MA2\res\toolbar2.bmp' is missing.

This file is in Tortoise SVN (I use the GUI) from way, way back.  I think.

The problem is that directory and file is long gone.  The directory does not exists nor does that file (I still have the file but not from back then).  MA2v52 is from Visual Studio 2013 which I recently deleted off my box.
That file is years old and why just now is it causing issues?  I did recently update to Visual Studio 15.3.3 which I think kicked this problem into gear.

Anyway.  I created that directories and that file and the missing file message when away but another came up:
1>Project not up to date because build input 'E:\Users\Valued Customer\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MA2v74\MA2\res\toolbar2.bmp' is missing.

So, I suspect this will go on forever and v0 was first went up to v100+.  (having v0...v100+ was a mistake)

I need my program to Build and hit Breakpoints while in Debug but I have no access to those old files  I cannot update them.

Please advise.

Comment: What type of files are in your project?

Comment: It's a MFC/C++ project so .h/.cpp,

Comment: Visual Studio does not have built-in support for SVN. There are VisualSVN and AnkhSVN plug-ins that add support for SVN. If you use the plug-in, nothing should be missing as it tracks file operations for you.

Comment: I did not mean to imply Tortoise SVN is built-in; I use the external Tortoise SVN for source control.

Comment: @user3533871 the problem is that if you perform file operations from Visual Studio, TortoiseSVN will not track them automatically and you may end up with missing files in your SVN working copy. You should install and use a plug-in to avoid such problems.